# Why is there an error when I call a function but not when I step through it?

Tags: r, ordinal

When I run the following code, I get an error: "object 'modelB' not found"

```
sim_analysis <- function(temp_data) {
  modelA <- clmm("Item1 ~ Total + (1 | Clust)", data = temp_data)
  modelB <- clmm("Item1 ~ Total + Group + (1 | Clust)", data = temp_data)
  return(anova(modelA, modelB)$`Pr(>Chisq)`[2])
}
sim_analysis(my_data)
```

But when I step through the function for temp_data = data, I get no error:

```
temp_data <- my_data
modelA <- clmm("Item1 ~ Total + (1 | Clust)", data = temp_data)
modelB <- clmm("Item1 ~ Total + Group + (1 | Clust)", data = temp_data)
anova(modelA, modelB)$`Pr(>Chisq)`[2]
```

The problem must have something to do with `clmm` (from the `ordinal` package) because when I make `Item1` responses numeric, remove the random effects, and do the exact same thing with `lm`, the function works fine.

A reproducible example was asked for, so here is some code to generate the data:

```
set.seed(12345678)
my_data <- data.frame(Clust = c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 10), rep(3, 10)),
                        Group = rep(c(0,1), 15),
                        Item1 = as.factor(sample(c(1, 2, 3, 4), 30, replace = TRUE)),
                        Total = sample(20:50, 30, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: I don't know this function, but why are you passing it deparsed formulas instead of proper formulas?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: the help page is not using quotes, but formulas: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ordinal/versions/2019.4-25/topics/clmm

Comment: In the help page linked above I can't see quotes in the formulas (see Examples at bottom)?

Comment: I use formulas in quotes out of habit (e.g., when doing measurement work using "lavaan" or "mirt," the formulas *must* be quoted) and because I often dynamically generate formulas. The quotes are not related to the problem

Comment: I believe the code you provided has an issue here: `temp_data <- data` since you're passing a function (i.e. `data()`) to **temp_data**

Comment: Good catch, gabrielet. When I simplified the example to put here on stack overflow, I forgot about the data() function. I have renamed the variables "my_data" to avoid that particular confusion